# Using iv/x to tonicize a key?

Tags: chords, harmony

Because V/x is so popular and useful, would iv/x have a good function as well? I’ve found that V and iv have very similar effects in terms of tension toward the tonic. Also, would V+/x be theoretically useful too? I find it is useful and very emotional as the primary dominant but I don’t know as for a secondary dominant.
Are these secondary chords common?

Comment: Do you know about plagal motion or cadences?

Comment: @AndyBonner yes, I am familiar with them. i was wondering if they are widely used as secondary chords and just generally more information about non V/x secondary chords.

Comment: While we could *assume* that by "x" you mean "any grade", using that letter is a bad choice, since `iv/x` literally means `fourth/tenth`. We could obviously assert that no grade after `vii` makes sense for fractional notation, but, nonetheless, I'd suggest to use something else anyway (especially if you're using the same case) in order to make it more clear, such as `iv/<x>` or `iv/<grade>`.

Comment: @musicamante since Roman numeral analysis assumes octave equivalence I doubt many people would mistake X for a Roman numeral instead of recognizing it as a variable.  It wouldn't hurt to be more explicit about it, though, as you suggest.  Also Roman numerals are typically spoken with cardinal numbers, not ordinals, so `iv/iii` is "four of three."  I've also never heard anyone use the word "grade" like this; were you looking for "degree"?

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I still struggle with some English technical terms and common rules. Most importantly, I never realized that Roman numerals are sometimes spoken as ordinal depending on the language or country: they are quite common in Italy (for obvious historical reasons - we even use them for some road signs) and practically always read as ordinals, with some exceptions probably borrowed from US culture such as film sequels, but not consistently: for instance, "Back to the Future - Part II" is spelled as "Ritorno al futuro parte *seconda*" but everybody just calls it "Ritorno al futuro due"; »

Comment: @phoog » coincidentally (and inconsistently), we use cardinals for Star Wars episodes ("Episodio Due", not "Secondo"), similarly to what sometimes used for book chapters written with Roman numerals, for which "Capitolo Secondo" is more correct. That said, we *always* use ordinals for musical degrees even for the "fractional" bass (as long as it's Roman), and cardinals are always for Arabic numerals only (such as inversions, like V², etc.). And, yes, I obviously meant degree (Italian "grado" can also be translated to "grade", but I don't always remember to contextualize the difference) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that “x” refers to a chord that is not the tonic (I or i). I would say neither iv/x or V+/x are that common but also not unheard of.

iv/x is not a commonly used term but it is easily understood. In some cases iv/x may be a diatonic chord so it may simply sound like a diatonic progression, for example Am-Em in C major. In other cases it may or may not sound like or be interpreted as a iv-x relationship depending on context, such as the duration of the chords or whether x is major or minor.

V+/x functions in a similar way to a regular secondary dominant. It just has different voice leading from the +5 note. Going to a major chord it resolves up a semitone and going to a minor chord it is a common tone.

The litmus test is your ears. What do they sound like to you? Remember, music is first, analysis is after the fact. If it works for you and you hear it that way that’s good enough.